# jquery ajax file spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project, and I have this javascript where #file-0-1-file is an input file id

```
function foo(){
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append( 'file', $("#file-0-1-file")[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    url: "../projectRest/file",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache:false,
    method: 'POST',        
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',        
    success: function (r) {
        console.log("success: " + r);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("error: " + e);
    }
});
}
```

That I want to receive here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("projectRest")
public class ProjectRestController {

  @PostMapping("file")
  public ResponseEntity<SuccessMessage> save(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

      return new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessMessage("All right!"), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Here my header request

```
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:233496
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundarys7qql1M65DsDjZ2U
Cookie:JSESSIONID=9v29UqpaxZsQVSyUg7qeluFg8xeq-6-NWxeU1hk3.diego-pc
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/songCommunityFactory/project/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN:d46a9a50-25fe-43a8-a15c-3d0bf6a22ff2
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarys7qql1M65DsDjZ2U
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG-20160528-WA0005.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarys7qql1M65DsDjZ2U--
```

And here Is the result

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present   

 org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver. handleMissingValue (RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)
```

I tried a lot of stuffs and I keep receive "Required request part 'file' is not present " and I don't know what is the problem, everything appears right for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I need to configure an Bean multipartResolver for allow me to upload files so I created

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

Now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax try changing into like this :

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data : {file : formData},
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gusti, I tried now I have a different error:  Current request is not a multipart request...Any guess?